# slice don't remove my object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function with the objective of search for one object with same value remove it for an global array and return it but it isn't removing

```
function removeAndget(p){
    var p2;
    for(var i =0;i<waiting_list.length;i++){
       if(waiting_list[i].le === p.le){
           p2 =waiting_list[i];

           console.log(waiting_list);

           waiting_list.slice(i,1);
           console.log(waiting_list);
           break;
        }
    }
return p2;
}
```

I need the object removed but for some reason it remains in, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say, I already have read the reference.

Comment: `slice` does not modify the array, `splice` does (notice the `p`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
```

not slice.

Comment: Spent 10 minutes to figure out why it doesn't works.... I didn't see the missing "P". Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're using `slice()` method on array with wrong format of arguments. If you want to use slice, the arguments format is different

```
slice(start, finish)
```

In your case for example `slice(i, i+1)`

Answer (score 0):

`slice()` does not mutate the array, `splice()` does

In your example, you can  use `splice(i, 1)`

Below are some details describing what the two functions do:

**slice:**

> The `slice(begin,end)` method returns a shallow ***copy*** of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

**splice:**

> The `splice(start,deleteCount)` method **changes the content of an array** by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.